# Accessing a NTLM-protected WCF Webservice with Android+ksoap2

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, ntlm, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to access a WCF web service from an android application to perform a basic user authentification. I'm using ksoap 3.1.1 and android 4.3. My main problem is that the webservice is protected by NTLM username / password, and i cannot figure out how to pass
these crenditials to the webservice.

Code snippet

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
request.addProperty("Login", username);
request.addProperty("Passwort", password);
request.addProperty("strMessage", "Hello SOAP!");                  
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.implicitTypes = true;                 
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);                 
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(ACTION, envelope);                  
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

I have searched multiple online ressources for how to do this, but without success.

Regards
Dave